# Can I use my Pi as an access point in headless mode?

Tags: networking, ssh, access-point

I'm using my Raspberry Pi in headless mode (through ssh) and I want to set it up as a wireless access point.

But if, acting as an access point, it forwards packets from the ethernet interface onto the wlan interface and vice versa, does that mean I will not be able to control it through ssh (since my ssh traffic that lands on the ethernet interface gets forwarded directly to wlan) ?

Forwarding as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but it results in me having to connect to my Pi's wireless access point on whatever computer I want to talk to it through ssh. I don't want to have to do this. I would like the controlling computer to be connected to another network.

Comment: That's the iptables rule you need `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`.

Comment: `-j MASQUERADE` for an access point, @jake?

Comment: @JaromandaX What the OP seems to want is rather a repeater, otherwise there would be no need to forward anything, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, packets land in the FORWARD chain *after* the local routing decision is taken, so packets addressed to the RPi itself (like SSH traffic) should not be affected by these rules:

[image]

However, you should note that if `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces belong to different IP subnets (e.g. `192.168.0.X` and `192.168.1.X`), simply forwarding packets between the two interfaces will not be enough to insure proper routing. You'll need that `-j MASQUERADE` option mentioned in the comments to make sure source addresses of IP packets are properly modified to make the replies routable. And since FORWARD chain doesn't allow packets to be modified, you'll have to enable NAT and use POSTROUTING chain to do this.

If you're happy with your current routing rules, I think you need to at least add a `-j ACCEPT` to make bare forwarding work.